# Flash Memory Issue in Arduino Yun

Tags: flash, memory, arduino

I am working on Arduino Yun and facing memory issue.

When I tried to upload any sketch on my board, it gives flash memory error stating "**You don't have enough disk space to install the utility software. You need to free at least 1MB of Flash memory**".

I look into the board and found, that rootfs is 99% used.

And then I tried to mount SD card using [Memory expansion](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/ExpandingYunDiskSpace) tutorial.

But again, I am facing the same flash memory issue while executing this memory expansion sketch.

I tried the following methods to clear the flash memory

1. Uploaded blank sketch
2. Reset the board using YUN RESET button
3. Upgraded the linino OS to this version
   "openwrt-ar71xx-generic-linino-one-16M-250k-jffs2-sysupgrade.bin"

But all in vain. I am stuck into this issue for last three days.

Can anyone help me to figure out how to clear flash memory and mount SD card for memory expansion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Memory expansion is the first thing you have to do, when you reflash your board. 
My favorite tool for doing this is "overlay-only -i"